# (unknown) Uncaught ReferenceError: u is not defined

Tags: wordpress

I have been getting this error on my WordPress Site and I keep wondering what exactly this error points to and what to do to get rid of it.

```
(unknown) Uncaught ReferenceError: u is not defined
    at d (<anonymous>:1:693)
    at <anonymous>:1:809
    at <anonymous>:1:814
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? I assume dev tools console... but you should add more details as to what you have tried/looked into already, where the error comes from, what theme and or plugins you have installed. Anything to help others troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. this error comes up on my page consistently in the developer console.  I noticed it as I decided to upgrade my website and update my plugins etc. I haven't done anything in particular but maybe if I can have a good understanding of the error message it will direct to to know exactly what change may have caused it.. Thanks.